# Pass generic type with actual literal value in type parameter

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure

I'm trying to pass a type parameter to a function

```java
public void foo(Class<T> class){
// do something
}
```

it's easy if i have to pass `Integer` or any simple `Class` by just passing `foo(ClassName.class)` but how can i pass this with generic type, i.e those class that have generic types? e.g

```java
Map<String,Object> m = foo(Map<String,Object>.class) // achieve something like this
Map<String,Object> m = (Map<String,Object>)foo(Map.class) // instead of something like this
```

Comment: You "can't", at least in as neat of a way as your example. There's the notion of a type token in some libraries, or you can use additional type parameters specifically for the case of handling collections, but overall at some point you will be unsafely casting to a generic `Map` and then either manually checking the content's type or returning that unsafe map.

Comment: You can not assign a `void` method call to a `Map`, regardless of any Generics issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what the receiver is doing, you may be able to get the necessary information from a [`ParameterizedType`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html) instance. `ParameterizedType` is a subclass of [`Type`,](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Type.html) as is `Class`, and many libraries that do binding or other reflection-intensive work use `Type` instead of `Class`.

In order to obtain a `ParameterizedType` instance, however, you have to define a type with the correct generic parameters. This is called a "type token," and often an anonymous instance is created.

Re-write your `foo()` method to inspect the class for generic type information:

```java
<T> void foo(Class<T> clz) {
    Type type = clz.getGenericSuperclass();
    if (type instanceof ParameterizedType) {
        ParameterizedType generic = (ParameterizedType) type;
        for (Type t : generic.getActualTypeArguments()) {
            System.out.println(t);
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println(clz);
    }
}
```

Now you can create a type token and pass it to your method:

```java
/* This doesn't work; type parameters are erased. */
Class<?> fail = Map<String, Object>.class 
/* This works; the type parameters are compiled into the anonymous type. */
class TypeToken<T> {}
Class<?> okay = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>() {}.getClass();
foo(okay);
```

Comment: thank you, I always wondered how to resolve this kind of issue, you are really helpful.

Answer (score -1):

You can use getClass method.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main{
   public static <T> void foo(Class<T> c){
      System.out.println(c);
   }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String,String> m = new HashMap<>();
        foo(m.getClass());
    }
}
```

Output

```
class java.util.HashMap
```